# Why I can't install Shutter?

Tags: 12.04, shutter

I want to install Shutter, because I took a screenshot with the PrintScreen button, but when I try to install Shutter from the software center or from the terminal using the shutter ppa, it says that I need to install libxml-simple-perl. When I try to install that, it throws me another dependency, then again, then again. Why I can't install Shutter? Even Synaptic won't install it. Is there any fix for it? Are there any alternatives for Shutter?

Comment: Also 'sudo apt-get -f install' don't do nothing

Comment: Since you are having problem with unmet dependencies; have a look at this question: [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies). Try the solutions listed there :)

Comment: Hi Tibi. Could you please try running `sudo apt-get -y install shutter` from a terminal and paste the output inside your question? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to install **Shutter**, BUT you can install other screenshot taking applications, like [this one which called Cleopix](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/09/cleopix-a-simple-screenshot-tool-for-ubuntu).

## To install Cleopix (it is paid)

You can simply click this button

[image]

Also take look at this link

- [Look It](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/06/linux-screenshot-tool-lookit-looking-for-testers)
- [Screen Cloud](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/06/screencloud-lets-you-take-share-ubuntu-screenshots-quickly)

---

**And** ther is other way without using <kbd>PrtScreen</kbd> button. Type in terminal
`gnome-screenshot`. You can also make launcher for that, and take screenshot via launching it. For that just copy this and paste into file called `screenshot.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Screenshot
Comment=Save images of your screen or individual windows
Exec=gnome-screenshot --interactive
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=applets-screenshooter
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GTK;GNOME;Utility;
NotShowIn=KDE;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gnome-utils
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=screenshot
Actions=Screen;Window;Area
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-screenshot

[Desktop Action Screen]
Name=Take a Screenshot of the Whole Screen
Exec=gnome-screenshot
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action Window]
Name=Take a Screenshot of the Current Window
Exec=gnome-screenshot -w
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action Area]
Name=Take a Screenshot of a Selected Area
Exec=gnome-screenshot -a
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

---

And after that make that file executable, using `chmod +x screenshot.desktop`.
And it is ready for use! Just add it to your unity launcher and that's all:

[image: That's how it will look like!]

Comment: I would recommend against buying Cleopix. It's far inferior to Stutter in all regards and will cost you $3.

Comment: @MHC I haven't tried, but I will keep it in mind. :-]

Comment: Thank You, geoh! The gnome-screenshot thing just works fine!!

Comment: always welcome @Tibi :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shutter/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install shutter
```

Comment: That's what I did and didn't work... :/

Comment: I just tryed the same on my Ubuntu 12.04 by giving the command **sudo apt-get install shutter** and it installed perfectly

Comment: @Tibi just to make it sure, you are installing this package in online mode, right?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the -y option to the install command. This tells apt-get to automatically install everything it needs. Assuming the dependencies are available of course.

```
sudo apt-get -y install shutter
```